# How can I remove the duplication between these C macros?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, code-duplication

I have the following couple of **C** pre-processor macros for creating test functions:

```
// Defines a test function in the active suite
#define test(name)\
    void test_##name();\
    SuiteAppender test_##name##_appender(TestSuite::active(), test_##name);\
    void test_##name()
```

which is used like this:

```
test(TestName) {
    // Test code here
}
```

and

```
// Defines a test function in the specified suite
#define testInSuite(name, suite)\
    void test_##name();\
    SuiteAppender test_##name##_appender(suite, test_##name);\
    void test_##name()
```

which is used like this:

```
test(TestName, TestSuiteName) {
    // Test code here
}
```

How can I remove the duplication between the two macros?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define test(name) testInSuite( name, TestSuite::active() )
```

However this doesn't reduce the amount of emitted C and machine code, only removes logical duplication.

Comment: Does this work? I thought that the preprocessor expanded macros in a single pass...

Comment: @Matthew: Macros are expanded while it is possible, not in a single pass, so chains of dependent macros are possible and can be used for creating barely debuggable code.
@Skizz: True, fixed that.
@Neil Butterworth: True about the emitted code, and I agree with you that this problem could hardly be solved. But logical duplication is elegantly removed.

Comment: I thought I'd tried this already without success but I was obviously confused! If you remove the trailing semi-colon I'll accept this answer. Thank you.

Comment: also important, a macro can't be replaced by itself: #define X(A) X(A) won't cause an infinite recursion :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#define test(name) testInSuite (name, TestSuite::active())
```